# How to order projects alphabetically in a Visual Studio solution with solution folders?

Tags: visual-studio

There is a bug in Visual Studio (2008, possibly 2005 too) that means the projects under solution folders are not automatically ordered alphabetically. What is the best workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Select a project, start to rename it (F2 or click it again) and then click a different project. The projects magically sort themselves into alphabetical order.